# php mysql prevent insert duplicate based on session id

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to prevent duplicate entries based on a php session id.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO mycart  ( `val_1`, `val_2`, `val_3`, `session` ) 
VALUES  ( '$val_1', '$val_2', '$val_3', '$session' )
```

This would force me to turn all columns into primary or unique keys which i can't do because the only thing unique can be the `session` column in groups.

```
+-+-------------+---------+
|1|fjdsklajkljkl|blue item|
+-+-------------+---------+
|2|fjdsklajkljkl|blue item|
+-+-------------+---------+
|3|T7RghUE1hQVWl|blue item|
+-+-------------+---------+
|4|xGQ8Jhifpu7jN|blue item|
+-+-------------+---------+
|5|xGQ8Jhifpu7jN|red item |
+-+-------------+---------+
```

From this diagram, only rows 1 and 2 are duplicates.  even tho blue item repeats, the string'd column is a different session.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check, if the value is there. You can easely do this with the [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) method.